# Catalog URL Rewrites stuck - core_url_rewrite empty

Tags: reindex

My catalog url rewrite has been stuck for days, the core url rewrite table was empty, but the url rewrites did show on the website.  we truncated the core url rewrite, the site url rewrite have gone, the reindex is still stuck and no rows showing in the core url rewrite.

any ideas please.

Answer (score 1):

Fixing weird URL Rewrites

Sometimes when you make changes to your products, or enable a certain extension, Magento might start to rewrite all your URLs to include a suffix "-1" or some other number. Within the URL Rewrites, Magento differentiates between System URLs and Custom URLs. If the System URLs are broken like this, you should not fix this by adding new Custom URLs.

Instead, open up phpMyAdmin, create a backup of your Magento database, and flush the Magento table core_url_rewrite (so that it becomes totally empty). Immediately afterwards, refresh the Catalog Url Rewrites under Index Management. This will regenerate all System URLs.

Comment: Good advice. Its advisable to trucate core_url_rewrite table and rewrite again this way it will keep it fresh and speed up your site.